# Surface of the curve $ y = \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{x^3} - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{x}$ rotated around the y-axis

Tags: calculus

So, I got the curve $y = \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{x^3} - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{x}$ and I need to get the surface of the solid I get by rotating it around the $y$ axis from $x=0$ to $x=4$.

The thing is, using the formula $\int 2 \pi * radius * length \ of \ the \ curve $, I can calculate the area from $x= \frac{3}{4} $ to $x = 4$, but I can't from $x = 0$ to $x= \frac{3}{4} $, since, in that interval, the curve makes a dip below $0$ and then goes up again, so I don't know how to calculate the radius in that case, since it isn't just $x$ as with the other interval.

So, my question is:
How should I calculate the radius?

Comment: You need to find the inverse function $x =$ something because you are rotating around the $y$-axis. Then split the function up where the local minimum is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the curve to the left and right by a vertical line through the low point of $y$.

Calculate the surface area of the right side and add the surface area of the left side.

Find the min point.

$$y = \frac{2}{3} x^{\frac{3}{2}} - \frac{1}{2} x^{\frac1{2}} \tag{1}$$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = x^{\frac1{2}} - \frac{1}{4} x^{-\frac1{2}} = 0 \tag{2}$$

$y$ takes on the minimum when:
$$x = \frac1{4} \tag{3}$$

[image]

The radius is $x$ since it is spun around the $y$ axis.

There are two integrals $\displaystyle x = \left[0,\frac1{4}\right]$ and $\displaystyle x = \left[\frac1{4},4\right]$.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Then I suppose the radius for the first integral is $1/4 - x$, right? And also, the radius for the interval $\displaystyle x = \left[\frac1{4},\frac3{4}\right]$ is $x$? Does the curve in the interval $\displaystyle x = \left[0,\frac1{4}\right]$ not affect it?

Comment: No, just use $x$. The rotation is still around the $y$ axis.

Comment: For $\displaystyle x = \left[\frac1{4},\frac3{4}\right]$ the curve that forms the surface is independent of the curve for $\displaystyle x = \left[0,\frac1{4}\right]$. Treat them separately. The surface areas add.

Comment: That should have been $\displaystyle x = \left[\frac1{4},4\right]$

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!